# Labeling Graphics in the Using the Bra Ket Notation

Tags: graphics

I'd like to label one of the axes of my graph as:

> $$ \frac{\langle \sigma_z \rangle}{2} $$

I am not sure how to add the `\langle` - $\langle$ - and `\rangle`- $\rangle$, in the standard Bra-Ket Notation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is also the `Typesetting` palette (under "Basic Math Assistant").

Answer (score 4):

This is *not* [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation).  You have no state vectors here.

You can type angle brackets using ESC < ESC and ESC > ESC.

Comment: Yeah, but I have typed the expectation value an operator using the Bra-Ket notation. That's what I meant. Anyway, when I type `ESC < ESC` and `ESC > ESC,' I get the same text on my axes -- not the angle brackets.

Comment: Figured it out by using the `\[RightAngleBracket]` and `\[LeftAngleBracket]` commands. Thanks.

Comment: @JunaidAftab You enter `\[RightAngleBracket]` by pressing the ESC key, then typing <, then pressing the ESC key again.  These are called angle brackets.  This is *not* bra-ket notation.  You are misusing the term.  I suggest you change the wording of your post because bra-ket notation, as in $\left\langle \psi \right|$, cannot be entered this way. That would be a different question with a different answer.